# Parsing to primitive types, based on user input in c#

Tags: c#, reflection, types, invoke, methodinfo

My code to do this uses reflection and strings that I give it, instead of user input.  Ultimately I would like the user to be able to say "float" "2.0" and have the computer say, yeah, that's a float, or "bool" "abc" to which the computer would say, that's no boolean it's heard of.

It would be simple enough to take the user input and convert it to a primitive type name, like "string" to "System.String", "float" to "System.Single", etc. (although if you know of a function to do that, that would be great too.)

Here's the code:

```
Console.WriteLine("1.0 => {0}", System.Single.Parse("1.0")); // this works fine.

Type t = Type.GetType("System.Single");              // for parsing floats
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("System.Single.Parse");  // "ambiguous" if use "Parse"
object[] parameters = new object[] { "1.0" };
float f = (float)(mi.Invoke(null, parameters));     // get null exception here.
Console.WriteLine("Was succesfully parsed to: " + f);
```

But I keep getting a null exception on the second to last line.  What's going on there?

Comment: Why not use TryParse? I think that would simplify this quite a bit.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cant just use **Single.Parse("1.0")** directly without using reflection?

Comment: @Chris:  Try Parse actually makes things more complicated for me, b/c of the funny out flag.

Comment: @Jeff: first and second sentence of the question.

Comment: @Jeff:  The reason is, I want to be able to have the user provide the type.  I suppose I could do one long switch statement based on the user input, but that doesn't seem very graceful.

Comment: Gotcha. I misunderstood. All the quotes and types in there are confusing - at least for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I keep getting a null exception on the second to last line. What's going on there?

Your `t.GetMethod` doesn’t work. The method is called `Parse`, not what you wrote. It might no longer be ambiguous – but that’s only because it now finds no method and silently returns `null`.

To make the call unambiguous, you need to specify the expected parameter types:

```
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("Parse", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
```

Comment: And we have a winner!  Thanks.  (I knew something was funny about that ambiguous parse statement, just didn't figure it out.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To do the same without using reflection:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ChangeType("42", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ChangeType("42.123", Type.GetType("System.Single")));
```

to avoid an exception for an invalid type, you could do:

```
string typeStr = "System.Single";

Type type = Type.GetType(typeStr);

if (type != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ChangeType("42", type));
}
```

Comment: Great.  That's nice and short.