# Parsing user provided enumeration values in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, reflection, enums, types

I'd like for the user to provide an enum name, say "Color", and a value, say "red", and tell them whether or not that is a member value of that enumeration, or if the enumeration even exists.

How can I do this?

In the past, I have used Type.GetType("UserProvidedType").Parse / Convert.ChangeType, but this doesn't appear to work when the user provided type is an enumeration.  Please see:
[Parsing to primitive types, based on user input in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682910/parsing-to-primitive-types-based-on-user-input-in-c)
for past solutions that don't appear to work in this context.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the value a string / an enum / an integral type? Could you provide a sample method signature?

Comment: the value to be recognized would be a string.  But the user also supplies the string representing the enum type.  So they would say "color", "red", and click a button that would then say, yes, red is a color.  or "mysteriousEnum" "red", click, and they'd get out "unrecognized Enum."  Also "Color" "Food" would return no such value in Enum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var type = Type.GetType("YourNameSpace.Color");
var belongs = Enum.GetNames(type).Any(o => o == "Red");
```

Comment: hm... that's odd.  When I try the above, oType is null.

Comment: var type = Type.GetType("System.Drawing.Color") does not work

Comment: Don't hurry for downvoting :-)

Comment: Here is a working sample `public enum Color { Red, Blue }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var type = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication7.Color");
            var any = Enum.GetNames(type).Any(o => o == "Red");
        }`

Comment: @Jani try with: System.Drawing.KnownColor

Comment: Sure it doesn't work, how could it know about the assembly that contains your type? Load the assembly the look for a type within

Comment: Hm... it does appear to work when I move the enum definition to outside the class.  Why do you say that is?  Thanks.